# Deactivate or delete unused fonts on Mac OS to optimize performance?

Tags: mac, performance, fonts

I have a lot of fonts on my Mac that I don't use any more (I used them for different graphical things). Obviously, the more fonts I have the "slower" my Mac is.

Should I deactivate or delete unused fonts to get better performance?

Comment: What is slower - it is not obvious that more fonts changes the speed especially to a noticeable extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivating them is fine. I group them in Font Book, then just deactivate the collections I don't need.

To be honest though, other than occasional apps updating the font cache, I haven't noticed much of a slow down.